# Excel - Concat values from multiple dynamic arrays into single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I have 3 dynamic array formulas.

In the below example, they would be the columns "X", "Y", and "Type".

For the purposes of example answers, let's use `X#`, `Y#`, and `Type#` as the cell references.

I want a 4th dynamic array formula that concatenates the 3 results, with delimiters, into a single 4th column.

| X | Y | Type | Desired Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | abcd | 0/3_abcd |
| 1 | 4 | efgh | 1/4_efgh |
| 2 | 5 | ijk1 | 2/5_ijkl |

I've tried to `HSTACK()` the 3 columns then use `BYROW()` on the result but couldn't figure out the LAMBDA part of it. Or even if it can be used like that. This feels like something that should be blindingly easy, but I just can't figure out the syntax to describe to Excel what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=A2#&"/"&B2#&"_"&C2#
```

---

`LAMBDA()` iteration is not needed as far I see however if one insist then can use `MAP()`

```
=MAP(A2#,B2#,C2#,LAMBDA(x,y,z,x&"/"&y&"_"&z))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Using CONCAT Formula

```
=CONCATENATE(F4#,"/",G4#,"_",H4#)
```

[image]

**If there’s any unclear information please let me know*